# Rewrite rule to redirect from http to https without extension

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I can access url without extension i.e I can access

'www.example.com/signUp/save' and 'https://www.example.com/signUp/save'

Now I am trying to redirect the following:

1. 'www.example.com/signUp/save.php' to 'https://www.example.com/signUp/save.php'
2. 'www.example.com/signUp/save' to 'https://www.example.com/signUp/save'

using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^signUp/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/signUp/$1
```

I am able to rewrite the first one but not the second. Also after writing this rewrite rule in my .htaccess file I get 'Not found' for 'www.example.com/signUp/save'

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^signUp/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/signUp/$1
```

Comment: Its giving the same result as before.

Comment: Im thinking it's likely not the rewrite then